# Merge DataFrame into another dataframe contaning all duplicates values, and the different ones will be replaced by string

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have two dataframe:df1 and df2

```
Index1=[5,10,15,20]
Index2=[5,10,13,15,20]
d1 = {'a' : pd.Series([1., 6., 3., 2.], index=Index1)}
d2 = {'a' : pd.Series([1., 5., 3., 2.], index=Index1)}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2)

      a
5   1.0
10  6.0
15  3.0
20  2.0    

      a
5   1.0
10  5.0
15  3.0
20  2.0
```

I want to merge them into another dataframe, and obtain an output like this:

```
      a
5   1.0
10  DIFF
15  3.0
20  2.0
```

Thanx a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mask`, `astype`, and `fillna`:

```
df1.mask((df1 - df2).astype(bool)).fillna('DIFF')
```

Output:

```
       a
5      1
10  DIFF
15     3
20     2
```